# Can A Dependent Variable be Factored Out of Integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

say
I have a the equation
$$y = xw + z$$

And I am trying to compute
$$\begin{aligned}\int \text{exp}((y - xw)^2 - w^2)dw &= \int\text{exp}(y^2 - 2xwy + x^2w^2 - w^2)dw
\\&= \int\text{exp}(y^2)exp(-2xwy + x^2 -w^2)dw \end{aligned}$$

Am I allowed to factor out the $\text{exp}(y^2)$ term considering $y = xw + z$ to get
$$\text{exp}(y^2)\int\text{exp}(-2xwy + x^2 - w^2)dw$$

I appreciate all of the swift replies. I did believe that was not correct, but needed a sanity check. Thank you all. To answer some comments, x and z are constants here.

Comment: No, for the same reason that if $y=x^2$ you cannot say that $\int ydx=y\int dx=yx+C$.

Comment: Do $x$ and $z$ vary with $w$ or are they constants?

Comment: You have $y-xw=z$ and therefore the integral is $\int\exp(z^2-w^2)dw=\exp(z^2)\int\exp(-w^2)dw.$

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't factor out $\exp{\left(y^2\right)}$ because $y$ depends on $w$. If it was independent, like say if $y$ is a constant or if $y$ equals anything that doesn't involve $w$, then yes you can pull it out.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not enough reputation to post this as a comment : my answer is that you cannot factor out $\exp(y^2)$ because it's dependent on $w$. But can you give more details about your variables ? are there any constant ?